# Get notification for when a control is enters view in c#?

Tags: c#, scroll

If I have a windows forms ScrollablePanel-based container and populate it with enough controls so that its actual size exceeds its view size, I can invoke the function ScrollIntoView to ensure Control X is in view.

But when the user scrolls the panel manually how can I get notification when Control X enters and exits the view?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Rectangle.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kh3ee9e.aspx) method with something like this:

```
if(container.Bounds.Contains(ControlX.Bounds))
{
   // I'm in the zone chief
}
```

This would go in the scroll event of the container control.